# Variables to define nested objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object and a few variables I'd like nested inside the variable but for some reason I can only ever get the first nest. Anything after that gives me an error stating that it couldn't read because it was undefined:

```
var date = 10;
var timestamp = 100;
Que[date] = {timestamp:{"test":"test"}};//this returns {10:{"timestamp":{"test":"test"}}}; for some reason
Que[date][timestamp] = {"test":"test"}; //errors saying, cannot read '100' undefined
console.log(Que);
```

I'm not sure why this is happening and I'd really like to resolve it with simple means. Btw the `Que` variable is global inside another script and predeterminietly contains `{"10":{"24":{"1":"test"}}};` which is likely why the `date` variable does work but the `timestamp` variable doesn't. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
date, and timestamp are both declared outside of the object, however i wish to use them as key's inside of the object.. 
uppon reading the mod suggested post and implementing what it contained, i ended up with another error

```
Que = {[date]:{[timestamp]:{"test":"test"}}};//this results in an unexpectd token error located at the [ before date
```

Comment: You are right, it has nothing to do with JSON. What you are having is an object and you are creating it using an *object literal*.

Comment: ignore that last comment! :O totaly didn't see the reference above, thanks ill be sure to check that out, didn't know about object literal! ^_^;

Comment: didn't help sadly, just added a new problem

Comment: I think the point you might be overlooking is that the variable `timestamp` of line 2 is completely different from the object literal key `timestamp` on line 3. If you want the code to behave like you expect, try: `Que[date] = {}` and then `Que[date][timestamp] = {test:'test'}` and you should get the structure you expect.

Comment: If you are not using a transpiler that converts ES6 to ES5 code then you cannot use the solution in your edit. Use the other one instead.

Comment: ok downloaded io.js but it didn't help at all. i still get the same error when i try and do it the final way mentioned. {[var]:"vale"};

Comment: @AndrewLavers what i wanted was for the value of "time stamp" to be the name for the key. not provide the data for they key. i.e. if timestamp = 100 i want the name of the key to be "100"

Answer (score 0):

I think there are more questions to be asked based off of your code snippet, but in your example `timesheet` is not defined, you can reference the key inside your JSON by using

```
Que[date]["timesheet"]
```

To access the object inside. The key that you're looking up with the [] notation should be a string.

Comment: I think the OP rather wants to use the value of `timestamp` as property key.